# How to reach a docker network from host using dns?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In local development, I often reach for docker-compose for services like db's that aren't moving much just for simplicity and isolation from my host machine.

Typical example right now - I'm developing a node based SPA with webpack and have a backing mongodb. On deployment these are tied together with Kubernetes.

Locally, while developing the *app* I definitely want to serve that from host because of productivity, but for the backing mongodb I rather just use a simple docker-compose. So I just set that up as I usually do:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.1.7-xenial
    command: "mongod"
    ports: 
      - 5000:27017
    volumes:
      - kb-front-db:/data/db
volumes:
  kb-front-db:
```

However, this time I got a collision on the host port 5000 because I already had used that for another project. And I do have quite a lot of these projects.

So… I really don't want to have to come up with some kind of port numbering scheme for all my projects to avoid collisions so I'm reaching for the docs to find a way to use dns or simply the bridge docker network name from the host…? But my searching skills fail me here, I just can't seem to find a way…? I find a lot of documentation about reaching *out* from a container to the host, but for some reason not the other way around without manually exposing with HOST_PORT.

I basically just want a way to connect to a docker container on the CONTAINER_PORT from the host using some kind of naming that's easier joggled in my head than port numbers?

Maybe I'm missing something super obvious here… Any tips highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to route traffic from host to Docker containers in bridge mode on OSX:

> Docker Desktop for Mac can’t route traffic to containers

The recommended solution is exactly what I'm trying to avoid:

> Our current recommendation is to publish a port, or to connect from another container. This is what you need to do even on Linux if the container is on an overlay network, not a bridge network, as these are not routed.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/